# NOTICE: Trying to get property of non-object... I Want to get the quantity of not returned books from the table where return status is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I Want to get the quantity of not returned books from the table where return status is NULL.......

```
 <?php 
     require_once("includes/config.php"); 

     if(!empty($_POST["studentid"])) {
        $studentid= strtoupper($_POST["studentid"]);  
        $sth = "SELECT count(*) as total from tblissuedbookdetails where Studentid=:studentid and retrunstatus=NULL";
        $query= $dbh -> prepare($sth);
        $query-> bindParam(':studentid', $studentid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> execute(); 
        $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        echo "<b>Already Issued: </b>".$results->fetch_array;
        echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',false);</script>";
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: This is the error I face..
(P.S Iam new to PHP )
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\library\admin\get_quantity.php on line 12

Comment: Are you sure your query is running successfully and not causing an error? Also, one of your columns (*`retrunstatus`*) looks like it's misspelled, that could be the cause.

Comment: which actually is the `line 12`?

Comment: This is Line 12 : 
echo "<b>Already Issued: </b>".$results->fetch_array;
@marlo

Comment: I really dont know what problems Iam facing ... in a similar php code, where I obtain student name from ID, thats working Fine .... and the spelling is fine... I misspelled it in the database table so thats why I have to write the same one in the code.... @Darren

Comment: @Darren The query runs perfectly fine in PHPmyAdmin

Comment: try `print_r($results->fetch_array())`

Comment: @marlo Still Not working .. In fact I got another error saying :
 Call to a member function fetch_array() on array

Comment: @PratikMishra, `print_r($results)` try this.

Comment: @marlo  Now Iam getting no error but the answer is not desired... As in There are two rows in the table with retrunstatus as NULL still Iam getting this as result :-
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 0 ) )

Comment: posted an answer.@PratikMishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `print_r`, the `$results` after `$query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` contains the data.

To access the data, use this.

```
<?php
//...
echo $results[0]->total
//...
?>
```

It seems that your query results to `total = 0`. You could check your database if it is not your expected output.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a Ton ! In addition to your suggestion I also had to change my SQL command slightly ... I had to put retrunstatus is NULL instead of retrunstatus=NULL

Comment: Welcome. :) I suggest you need to research some tools for your PHP-mySQL-HTML development. DBeaver is free for SQL